# Drawing graphs in Django

Tags: django, graph

I want to draw a graph in my Django-based site, to look like these one:

[image: http://cssglobe.com/lab/csslinegraph/img.gif]

How can I do this?

Comment: You might look into Google's Charting API and duck the issue of generating charts on your own server: http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try one of these Django apps:

1. [django-googlecharts](http://github.com/jacobian/django-googlecharts) (archived)
2. [django-graphs](https://github.com/kenkeiter/django-graphs) (no longer maintained)

Also, see answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609944/charts-in-django-web-applications)

Answer (score 10):

Try [django-chartit](https://github.com/chartit/django-chartit) - licensed BSD 2-clause, last updated 2018

Answer (score 0):

Try [django-graphos](https://github.com/agiliq/django-graphos) (last updated 2017). It supports many chart types.