# Defining ways to visualise admin fields - Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to add graphs to the admin interface, problem is that I have not found any documentation regarding this.

I'm sure there are generally accepted ways of customizing the way fields are displayed, and I do not wish to follow any problematic route.

---

Any ideas?

---

**Edit:**

this is a model I'm trying to reproduce!

> **Unicorn**: name, horn length (cm), daily grass grazed (sparkline), average speed (m/s)

daily grass grazed is a **OneToManyField**

and this is what I mean by **sparkline** 
[image]

Comment: Give us an idea of what a graph is in this context. Like a bar chart of some numeric value for a bunch of rows?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of using Highcharts via the Django admin:

http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/rprasad/2011/08/30/highcharts-django-admin/

Answer (score 0):

Django does not have built in report/graph libraries as far as i know so you should use 3rd party library for generating graphs and customize your admin interface.

See [this SO question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609944/charts-in-django-web-applications).